# SQL conditional join Teradata

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I am trying to join the following two tables T1 and T2 on T1.id=T2.id, T1.MonA=T2.MonB such that

1. Whenever MonA=MonB (iow an entry can be found in both tables),
   perform an ordinary join. This is the case for instace for ID A,
   MonA=MonB=3
2. If a MonB entry is in table T2 but no equal MonA entry can be found in
   Table T1, the join shall take from table T1 the row where MonA is
   maximal. In the sample tables, this is the case for both last rows.
3. MonA from T1 which are not in T2 shall be ignored

The condition T1.id=T2.id is a necessary precondition, so this always needs to be true!

```
Table T1
ID            MonA     Data
A             2        BBB
A             3        CCC
B             4        DDD
B             5        EEE
B             11       EEE
```

```
Table T2
ID            MonB     Organ
A             3        Liver
B             5        Heart
B             7        Kidney
```

Here is, how the result should look like

```
ID       MonA    MonB    Data       Organ
A        3       3       CCC        Liver
B        5       5       EEE        Heart
B        11      7       EEE        Kidney
```

I need this to be performed in Teradata SQL and honestly have no idea currently how to tackle the problem. Thanks for help!

EDIT: The may be several entries with identical ID, MonA=MonB, but different Data/Organ columns and i want all of them in the resulting table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do a join of t1 with t2 as follows

```
--gets all of the matching records by (id,mona) pairs from t1 with (id,monb) from t2
select a.id,a.mona,b.monb,a.data,b.organ
  from t1 a
  join t2 b
    on a.id=b.id
   and a.mona=b.monb
union all /*Here you want only from t2 not there in t1 by id*/
   select b.id,x.mona,b.monb,x.data,b.organ
     from t2 b
left join t1 a
       on a.id=b.id
      and a.mona=b.monb
left join (select row_number() over(partition by id order by mona desc) as rnk
                  ,id
                  ,mona
                  ,data
             from t1 
           )x
       on b.id=x.id
      and x.rnk=1 /*pick up only the largest values arranged by mona*/
    where a.mona is null /*Gets only the missing records from t2 which are not in t1*/
```

Comment: K, I am getting there. I see my first mistake in my approch was to use a partition and descending rank for both MonA and MonB, which lead to problems when they had different covering sets. The union still makes some problems (imcompatible select-lists), but I will keep trying. Laters.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! I did not really no of the union method (Still learning SQL) and the idea is really nice!

Comment: Short remark: I moved the windowing/partition into the join condition - makes the union much easier as you don't have to select the columns individually.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the expected result:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.mona,t2.monb,t1.data,t2.organ
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2
    ON t1.id=t2.id
QUALIFY
   Row_Number() 
   Over (PARTITION BY t2.id, t2.organ 
                  -- prefer same entry in both tables
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.mona = t2.monb THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                  -- otherwise take max monA
                  ,t1.mona DESC -- ) = 1
```

Comment: I will try whether case within the partitioning works. However, how will you use the partition when t2 has several more columns which all need to be included, and why is t2.organ in the partitioning at all? Thx for help!

Comment: You can simply add ANDed conditions to the WHEN. And t2.organ is added to PARTITION because you wanted all rows from t2 returned (should be partitioned by a unique column combination)

Comment: Hi Doneth. Considering t2 has a lot more columns, is there any avoiding naming the all explicitly in the "Partition By" line? In the above solution I can simply use "select *'... If there were a solution for this, I would immediately give it a shot. Looks really nice and clean!

Comment: I meant "avoiding enumerating them all", could not change the edit any longer.